# Looping through table rows when the url doesn't change with selenium

Tags: python, selenium

[image: selenium]

This is what the problem looks like. I'm supposed to go through this table with 2995 rows. Each of these rows can be double clicked which opens up a details page for it. I'm supposed to open a row, check some value from the details page, and go to the next one, doing the same. The table itself has no incremental identifier, the ID in the first column is a random string. How would I go about this?

Comment: Does the details page opened on the same web tab or a new tab / window is opened each time?

Comment: Can you share a link to that page?

Comment: @Prophet Sorry, this is an internal work db with a username and pass, not even supposed to post a screenshot... It opens on the same tab, but the url never changes, no matter what I click in table, or in new view.

Comment: So, you just need to open each those rows one by one? Can you row elements class names etc?

Comment: Yes, I need to open each one of them. What do you mean by "Can you row elements class names etc?"?

Comment: Sorry, typo. I asked to show row elements properties. But I think itronic's solution is OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works:

```
tableRows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='v-data-table__wrapper']/table/tbody/tr")
for tr in tableRows:
    tr.click()
//do the check on the details page
```

Comment: Looks like it could, I'll check it out soon. Is the CSS selector equivalent of that "div.v-data-table__wrapper > table > tbody > tr"?

Comment: Yup, that worked like a charm! Had to put a small time.sleep before it though :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath to select each row in a loop.

```
//*[@id="left-sidebar"]/div[1]/nav/ol/li[2]/ol/li[x] // Where x is your loop iterator
```

You can do the same with css selector

```
#left-sidebar > div.left-sidebar--sticky-container.js-sticky-leftnav > nav > ol > li:nth-child(x) // Where x is your loop iterator
```

This is of course an example (The element is the li's on the stackoverflow left side bar)

EDIT: Code example with

```csharp
var elements = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='tableau']/tbody/tr"));

for (int x = 0; x < firstResult.Count; x++)
{
  var tr = driver.FindElement(By.XPath($"//*[@id='tableau']/tbody/tr[{ x }]"));

// Without selecting

var tr = elements[x];

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your example.

Comment: Just edited my awnser, the code has not been tested and hand written. Can contain typo errors, but the logic is here